# a label in html followed by a small png image

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a label in my code like below

```
<label class="col-sm-3" >Redeem Game points</label>
```

After the label, I have an input field like below

```
<input class="form-control payment-new" type="text">
```

I want to put a small image(a question mark) after my label ends.

How do I do that? 
Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gv0raymw/1/).

If not with an image, Is it possible to use font awesome and then have my image updated there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using either font-awesome or the `<img>` tag.
The below is using font-awesome.

```html
 <label class="col-sm-3" >Redeem Game points<i class="fa fa-question" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
<input class="form-control payment-new" type="text" name="order[coupon_code]" id="order_coupon_code">

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c7082764ea.js"></script>
```

Thee below code is using the image tag.

```html
 <label class="col-sm-3" >Redeem Game points<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/49/49243.png"></label>
<input class="form-control payment-new" type="text" name="order[coupon_code]" id="order_coupon_code">
```

I chose an image of some random size. You can use any image you want and if you want to increase the size of the question mark in the font awesome method. Just add an additional class like `fa-2x` or `fa-3x`

Comment: the trouble is I have rails form and I can not directly do it.